# Adding a C# enum value to a Navigation URI

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone application. I make the question here because I think a silverlight question.

I have defined the following Navigations URIs on App.xaml:

```
<!-- Navigation links-->
<nav:UriMapper x:Name="UriMapper">
    <nav:UriMapper.UriMappings>
        <nav:UriMapping Uri="/Destination" MappedUri="/Views/Tourism/Common.xaml?Type=1"/>
        <nav:UriMapping Uri="/Points" MappedUri="/Views/Tourism/Common.xaml?Type=2"/>
    </nav:UriMapper.UriMappings>
</nav:UriMapper>
```

And the following C# enum:

```
public enum TourismItemType
{
    Destination = 1,
    PointOfInterest = 2,
    Content = 3
}
```

I want to change the '**1**' on MappedUri="/Views/Tourism/Common.xaml?Type=**1**" with the value obtained from **TourismItemType.Destination**.

I think, I can do that:

And do it programatically, but is there any way to access the value represented by TourismType.Destination on XAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by passing the value of the enum as a string and then parsing it into an enum in the OnNavigatedTo event.

```
MappedUri="/Views/Tourism/Common.xaml?Type=PointOfInterest"
```

and then in common.xaml:

```
string selectedType = "";
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Type", out selectedType))
{
    var tit = Enum.Parse(typeof (TourismItemType), selectedType, true);

    // do something with `tit`...
}
```